# Is it possible to mirror an EventStore without having to write a custom client?

Tags: eventstoredb

Is it possible with just using the `EventStore.ClusterNode.exe` to create a mirror of another EventStore?  What I am trying to accomplish is having a readonly copy of the data local to the development and support teams so that we can improve performance of our debugging/support scenarios.

Lets say that I have an EventStore setup at location `A`.  All services for running that environment are located at `A`.
Support is located over WAN at `B`, and Development is at `C`, which is over WAN also.

I would like to be able to bring up `B` and `C` independently without `A` having to be reconfigured (aside from the initial setup of allowing network access).

This way Locations `B` and `C` can query their local copies without the slowness of the WAN.

I assumed this was possible, but I don't see this documented online or I don't understand what I am looking for.
I tried manually to figure this out, but all I got on the new mirror as only new events generated.

Comment: I thought clustering does exactly that

Comment: I got the sense that clustering did a lot more than that.  I thought that it would also make both nodes writable, make sure a certain percentage has the update before guaranteeing the write, and things around the management of 'primary nodes'

Comment: Is very dangerous to do that, since all three nodes will accept writes! Do not be lazy, just write a little client that subscribes to the production db and makes a copy. Is not that hard.